# Taking screen shot of a SurfaceView in android

Tags: android

I am using following method to taking screen shot of a particular view which is a SurfaceView.

```
public void takeScreenShot(View surface_view){

    // create bitmap screen capture
    Bitmap bitmap;
    View v1 = surface_view;
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
    byte[] imageData = bos.toByteArray();

}
```

the problem is its giving me the whole activity screen image. But I need to take screen shot of the particular view. I tried other ways but those give me a black screen as screen shot, some posts says that it requires rooted device.
Can any one help me please. I'm in need of this solution. Help me....

Comment: Hello, by "the problem is its giving me the whole activity screen image", do you mean that you are able to capture the whole surface AND the surfaceview? I am facing the same problem, but with your code, I am still getting the whole activity with all the elements visible but the SurfaceView (I'm getting a black frame). Could you tell me what is exactly surface_view?

Answer (score 2):

Surface view is a view but item on surface view like bitmap or other object are not any view. So while you capture surface view it will capture every thing on the surface. You have to use other view like image view or other above the surface view and then capture those view.

First get the view whose picture want to take then do this

```
            Bitmap bitmap;
            View rv = **your view**
            rv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rv.getDrawingCache());
            rv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            // Write File to internal Storage

            String FILENAME = "captured.png";
            FileOutputStream fos = null;

            try {

                fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("","FileNotFoundException: "+e1.getMessage());

            }

            try {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: I tried to make a screenshot of SurfaceView this way, but output bitmap width and height is -1 ... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);            
v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
v.draw(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the bitmap, you can copy only a part of it like this:

```
 private Bitmap copyBitmap(Bitmap src){

     //Copy the whole bitmap
     //Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(src);

     //Copy the center part only
     int w = src.getWidth();
     int h = src.getHeight();
     Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, w/4, h/4, w/2, h/2);

     return newBitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method its works fine for me actually surfaceview does not work with v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  i do this by using this code.

```
 jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            camera.startPreview();
            Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray
                    (data, 0, data.length);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pd.setTitle("Wait!");
            pd.setMessage("capturing image.........");
            pd.setIndeterminate(false);
            pd.show();

            progressStatus = 0;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (progressStatus < 100) {
                        // Update the progress status
                        progressStatus += 1;

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(20);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // Update the progress status
                                pd.setProgress(progressStatus);
                                // If task execution completed
                                if (progressStatus == 100) {
                                    // Dismiss/hide the progress dialog
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0, 0, cameraBitmap.getWidth(), cameraBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            if (rotatedBitmap != null) {
                rotatedBitmap = combinebitmap(rotatedBitmap, bitmapMap);
                Random num = new Random();
                int nu = num.nextInt(1000);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
                ByteArrayInputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);
                String picId = String.valueOf(nu);
                String myfile = "Ghost" + picId + ".jpeg";
                File dir_image = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +//<---
                        File.separator + "LiveCamera");          //<---
                dir_image.mkdirs();                                                  //<---

                try {
                    File tmpFile = new File(dir_image, myfile);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        fos.write(buf, 0, len);
                    }
                    fis.close();
                    fos.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            " Image saved at :LiveCamera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    camera.startPreview();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{dir_image.toString()}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            }
                        });


                safeToTakePicture = true;

            }

        }

    };
```