# Text and line drawn on ToggleButton canvas appear on screen but not on screenshot

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, screenshot, togglebutton

I have created a view `MyToggleButton` that extends `ToogleButton`. I overwrite the Togglebutton's `onDraw` method to draw a line on the button and to rotate it's text.

Here is `MyToggleButton`:

```
package com.example.gl.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MyToggleButton extends ToggleButton {

    public float textRotation=0;

    public MyToggleButton(Context context, float rotationValue) {
        super(context);

        textRotation=rotationValue;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

        TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
        textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

        canvas.save();

        //paint
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(7);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        canvas.drawLine(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, (float) (canvas.getHeight() / 2 + 400), (canvas.getHeight() / 2), paint);

        canvas.rotate(textRotation, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);

        getLayout().draw(canvas);

        canvas.restore();

    }


}
```

After that I want to get a screenshot of and view it and for that I use the `takeScreenshot()` method that is called by pressing the 3rd button on screen. The screenshot code is based on [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android). The same approach is followed in other posts on stackoverflow, and in various sites and  tutorials I found around.

Here is the `MainActivity` that I use:

```
package com.example.gl.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //add 3 buttons
        addButtons();

    }


    private void addButtons(){

        LinearLayout linear1= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.vert1);

        //MyToggleButton with rotated text
        MyToggleButton btn1 = new MyToggleButton(this,0);
        btn1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btn1.setTextOff("Button 1 not rotated");
        btn1.setTextOn("Button 1 not rotated");
        btn1.setText("Button 1 not rotated");
        linear1.addView(btn1);

        //MyToggleButton with normal text
        MyToggleButton btn2 = new MyToggleButton(this,50);
        btn2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btn2.setTextOff("Button 2 rotated");
        btn2.setTextOn("Button 2 rotated");
        btn2.setText("Button 2 rotated");
        linear1.addView(btn2);

        //button to create screenshot
        Button btn3 = new Button(this);
        btn3.setText("Create bitmap");
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takeScreenshot();

            }
        });
        linear1.addView(btn3);



    }

    //Screenshotcreator
        private void takeScreenshot() {
            try {
                View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

                // create bitmap screen capture
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());

                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                ImageView imageView1 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
```

Here is the layout of `MainActivity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.gl.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relative1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/vert1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that although everything looks ok on the screen, the screenshot's bitmap lacks the drawn line and the rotated text.

[image: You can see the problem here. Screen is OK, screenshot is not.]

What could be the reason for that strange result in the bitmap?

Notice that that the devices back-home-recents buttons are missing from the screenshot, as also the status bar information (time etc). I doubt that this has to do something with my issue. Those elements do not belong in my app so it is expected for them to not appear in the view I get with get with `v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();` But the canvas on which I draw the rotated text and the line do belong to that view.

My question is: Why does the drawn line and the rotated text do not appear on the screenshot, and how can I modify my code to get a screenshot with them on too?

I don't want to do something that needs a rooted device and also I cannot use MediaProjection API because this was added in API 21 but I want my app to run on android 4.4 (API 19) too. Finally, I am aware of the existence of external libraries such as Android Screenshot Library or this: [https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2793](http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2793) , but I would rather not use any external library.

P.S. maybe this is related:[Surfaceview screenshot with line/ellipse drawn over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316861/surfaceview-screenshot-with-line-ellipse-drawn-over-it?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both `btn1.isDrawingChaceEnabled()` and `btn2.isDrawingChaceEnabled()` return `false`.

Even if you call `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` on the RootView, it is not set as `true` recursively on all his Children View  (I tested it with Log.d).
That means that the drawing cache of your ToggleButton will be empty as explained in the `android.view.View.getDrawingCache()` javadoc.

```
/**
 * <p>Calling this method is equivalent to calling <code>getDrawingCache(false)</code>.</p>
 *
 * @return A non-scaled bitmap representing this view or null if cache is disabled.
 *
 * @see #getDrawingCache(boolean)
 */
```

So make sure you set `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` for each of the views you are interested in.
For example I added the following lines to your code:
in MainActivity

```
    btn1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    btn2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

[And it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMmwz.png)