# How to capture a screenshot programmatically with Lollipop

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection

The [Media Projection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary.html) package is new Lollipop, and allows an app to capture the device's screen in realtime for streaming to video. I was hoping this could also be used to capture a single still screenshot, but so far I have not been successful. Of course, the first frame of a captured video could work, but I'm aiming for a perfect, lossless screenshot matching the pixel resolution of the device. A still from a captured video cannot provide that.

I've tried a lot of things, but the closest I came to a solution was to first launch an [invisible activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android/2700683#2700683). This activity then follows the [API example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture) for starting screen capture, which can include asking the user's permission. Once screen capture is enabled, the screen image is live in a SurfaceView. However, I cannot find a way to capture a bitmap from the SurfaceView. There are lots of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724237/taking-screen-shot-of-a-surfaceview-in-android) and [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091703/how-to-create-and-save-a-screenshot-from-a-surfaceview) about this, but no solutions seem to work, and there is some evidence that it is [impossible](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-platform/xHIActZZ9PA/Ur4E0BuEKvEJ).

Any ideas?

Comment: would a screenshot of app - minus the status bar be good enough?

Comment: @BojanKseneman Yes, but keep in mind that this should be able to screenshot anything on the device (except for secure surfaces)-- not just my app.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/mtsahakis/MediaProjectionDemo/blob/master/src/com/mtsahakis/mediaprojectiondemo/ScreenCaptureImageActivity.java ?

Comment: Oh, I am not sure if you can capture other apps without root. That would be a security issue. You can do some hacks with reflection to call hidden android code tough, it has screenshots functionallity

Comment: @BojanKseneman you definitely can in Lollipop, it just asks the user permission first. See the API demo linked above.

Comment: @shkschneider, thanks for the link. The ImageReader class may be just what I need!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't capture the contents of a SurfaceView.

What you can do is replace the SurfaceView with a Surface object that has an in-process consumer, such as [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html).  In the android-ScreenCapture example linked from the question, `mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay()` wants a Surface to send images to.  If you create a SurfaceTexture, and use that to [construct a Surface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html#Surface(android.graphics.SurfaceTexture)), the images generated by the MediaProjection will be available from an OpenGL ES texture.

If GLES isn't your thing, the [ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html) class can be used.  It also provides a Surface that can be passed to `createVirtualDisplay()`, but it's easier to access the pixels from software.